# Jquery dropdown remove class after disappears

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this code for a dropdown and I need to  remove the class 'hovered' on '#products' after the menu slides up and has disappeared. How do I do this? Currently it disappears straight away onmouseout

Thanksfor any help in resolving this! :-)

```
$(function() {
    var divTop = 168;
    $('#products div ul').css({'margin-top': '-' + divTop + 'px','float':'left'});

    $('#products > a,#products div').hover(function(){
        $('#products').addClass('hovered');
        $('#products div ul').show().stop().animate({'margin-top': '0'});
    },function(){
        $('#products').removeClass('hovered');
        $('#products div ul').show().stop().animate({'margin-top': '-' + divTop + 'px'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) in the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) callback, like this:

```
$(function() {
    var divTop = 168;
    $('#products div ul').css({'margin-top': '-' + divTop + 'px','float':'left'});

    $('#products > a,#products div').hover(function(){
        $('#products').addClass('hovered');
        $('#products div ul').show().stop().animate({'margin-top': '0'});
    },function(){            
        $('#products div ul').show().stop().animate({'margin-top': '-' + divTop + 'px'}, function() {
          $('#products').removeClass('hovered');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for that. Will be ticking that off as answered in 5

Answer (score 0):

You could probably put

```
function(){
$('#products').removeClass('hovered');
}
```

as the callback of the [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly, it seems like you just need to make use of the callback function of .animate() (REF: http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$(function() {
    var divTop = 168;
    $('#products div ul').css({'margin-top': '-' + divTop + 'px','float':'left'});

    $('#products > a,#products div').hover(function(){
        $('#products').addClass('hovered');
        $('#products div ul').show().stop().animate({'margin-top': '0'});
    },function(){
        $('#products div ul').show().stop().animate({'margin-top': '-' + divTop + 'px'}, function(){
            $('#products').removeClass('hovered');
        });
    });
});
```